Available updates not showing up in GNOME software
Listing available updates with "apt update" and "apt list --upgradable" shows that there are updates available, but they don't show up in GNOME Software. Is there any way to fix this? The only additional plugin I installed is the flatpak plugin.
The updates also show up in pkcon update.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.

Please add to the question what the updates are. Have you tried sudo apt get update and sudo apt get upgrade? If you do not want to upgrade just say no when it prompts you.

The problem isn't the updating process itself - apt get upgrade works perfectly fine, but I'd like the updates to show up in GNOME Software, so I can update everything in one place.

as for you rcomment about the absence of Flatpak updates, how did you install Flatpak and did you include sudo apt install flatpak gnome-software-plugin-flatpak after installation?

Okay, so flatpak updates actually work! There just weren't any available until now! Regular deb packages still don't show up, unfortunately.

Perhaps this It's FOSS post addresses your issue.

No, that just installs it, I've already installed GNOME Software and the flatpak plugin.
